# Catcodes of unicode characters with \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

Tags: catcodes

I don't understand why this is generating an error message...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\catcode`ẟ=\active
\end{document}
```

As the `inputenc` suggests, I'm using `pdflatex`.* Shouldn't the `inputenc` import cause ẟ to behave like any other letter?

*I need features `xelatex` doesn't support.

Comment: It looks like you can achieve the effect I needed by using `DeclareUnicodeCharacter`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

TeX does not know about unicode. For TeX, a character is simply 1 byte in the input. But unicode is multibyte. `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` is an elaborate hack to fool TeX into accepting those multibyte chars.

When you write a file using `utf8` encoding, each character in the file can be coded into 1, 2 or 3 bytes (or even 4 bytes for very exotic alphabets). If the character is in the ASCII standard, it takes only 1 byte, and everything is OK for TeX. Those characters have a binary code of the form `0xxxxxxx`, i.e. the first bit is zero (because ASCII standard comprises codes only up to 127).

The unicode char ẟ that you used in your input, is coded in utf8 as three bytes, of binary values: `11100001`, `10111010` and `10011111`. Note that all of those begin with a bit of value `1`, which is the "mark" utf8 uses to denote that they are not ASCII, but multibyte chars.

However, for TeX those three bytes are simply three chars, with codes `"E1`, `"BA` and `"9F` respectively (`"` is the hexadecimal prefix for TeX). What `inputenc` basically does is to make the character with code `"E1` an active char, and define the command associated with that character in such a way that if after it came characters `"BA` and `"9F` then the TeX command `\delta` is issued.

I guess that you can understand now why you can't alter the catcodes of Unicode characters.

XeTeX or LuaTeX, on the other hand, use a TeX engine capable of accepting "characters" 32bits wide, and the input phase "translates" utf8 to the appropiate unicode point, which is what TeX "eyes" see.

Comment: @egreg, David_Carlisle, thanks. I really appreciate your kind comments

Comment: i've noted this answer down as the basis of an entry in the uk tex faq; i hope that's ok with you.  it will take some time to appear in that form, since i've a vast backlog of stuff to add (and i work on my own, which is probably a mistake).

Comment: @wasteofspace no problem at all! Glad of being helpful.