# Extracting characters from the new libertine (with pdflatex)

Tags: symbols, pdftex, characters, libertine

The issue: I need to access e.g. `libertine`'s delta glyph in `pdflatex`.

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76305/how-does-libertine-type1-work?rq=1) notes that the `\libertineGlyph` command is no longer provided by the latest version of the `libertine` package. It also notes that the replacement `libertineotf` doesn't work with `pdftex`. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79261/17049) suggests two workarounds (short of installing an older version).

1. Copy the definition of `\libertineGlyph` from the legacy version of the file.

   I cannot get this to work because `libertine.sty` uses a macro `\define`. This doesn't seem to be provided when you import the three packages required by `libertine`, and it isn't a standard command.
2. It suggests using `\char` instead.

   E.g. `\char934` doesn't work, presumably for the reasons which [JLDiaz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/12571/jldiaz) explained so clearly in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86300/17049).

I'd be very grateful for a working method.

Edit: I'm specifically looking for a "text" delta rather than a "maths" delta. Cf:

[image]

Comment: I don't think that the fonts for `pdflatex` make available the glyphs that previously one could get with `\libertineGlyph`. It's not just a definition problem.

Comment: But one can get those fonts back (for `pdfLatex`) by installing the old package?

Comment: Possibly; a *very* hard task.

Comment: If you only need one glyph, I suggest a dirty “working method”: Compile a minimal example with XeLaTeX, e.g. `\documentclass{standalone}\usepackage{libertine}\begin{document}\char934\end{document}`, and `\includegraphics` the resulting PDF with pdfLaTeX.

Comment: You could still install `libertine-legacy` in a local texmf tree.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, so let me make a rather adventurous proposal. I will assume you have the TeXLive 2012 distribution, as this is the only one I am familiar with.

1. install `libertine-legacy` in the local texmf tree
2. find the file `libertine.sty` in `texmf-local/tex/latex/libertine-legacy/` 
   and rename it to `libertine-legacy.sty` (we are not going to use it as it may
   certainly create havoc with the newer `libertine.sty` which is in `2012/texmf-dist`)
3. find the file `libertine.map` in `texmf-local/fonts/map/dvips/libertine-legacy/`
   and rename it to `libertine-legacy.map`
4. go to `texmf-local/web2c` and add the line `Map libertine-legacy.map` to the file `updmap.cfg` (you may have to create that file)
5. run `texhash` on the repertory `texmf-local`
6. run `updmap-sys` or `updmap` depending on your previous habits (I personally only and exclusively use `updmap-sys`)

You are now ready to access the Greek glyphs from the legacy libertine type-1 fonts in the following manner:

```
\documentclass{article}

%% the next two lines are for the *new* libertine
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}

%% these next lines are for the *legacy* libertine, especially the Greek glyphs
\begingroup
\makeatletter
  \newcommand*\DeclareTextGlyphX[5]{%
  % \DeclareTextGlyphX{fxl}{U}{fxla7}{uniA7F1}{241}
  % #1=basefont #2=encoding #3=fontfamily #4=glyphname, #5=position
  \global\@namedef{legacy#1#4}{{\fontfamily{#3}\fontencoding{#2}\selectfont\char#5\relax}}}
\input{fxl.inc}
\endgroup

\begin{document}

\legacyfxldelta

\legacyfxlDelta

\end{document}
```

The files of my version of the legacy package are dated from December 2011. I hope this is the latest version, and that there has not been in the meantime changes in the font names in the legacy thing.

Let me insist that what I describe here does not replace the new `libertine` with the `libertine-legacy`. Both need to be installed: the new one in your main tree, the legacy one in the local tree. And you need to change the names of the legacy .sty and .map files as indicated, and then don't forget to do `texhash` and `updmap-sys`.

[image: delta and Delta from libertine-legacy]

Comment: This looks interesting. If the `newtx` approach below doesn't play out, I'll definitely chase it up. (Though manual installation is a bit fiddly in MiKTeX.)

Comment: @Mohan: What do you mean with “fiddly”? See Stefan Kottwitz’ answer to [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows) and follow steps 1–3 of jfbu. For steps 4–6 above see [How to install MathTime Pro 2 fonts on MikTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74698/how-to-install-mathtime-pro-2-fonts-on-miktex), though some steps there are redundant.

Comment: @Mohan Update: [Manual font installation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88423/manual-font-installation).

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of libertine (2012-12-07) does support Glyph commands but only for xeLaTeX and luaLaTeX users.  To get a glyph like delta, I suggest using newtxmath with the libertine option.

Update:  It seems that the newtx package was improperly installed by MiKTeX.  As a stopgap, you can edit the system `updmap.cfg` to change `ntx.map` to `newtx.map` and execute

```
initexmf --mkmaps
```

Then the libertine option of newtxmath will work and `$\updelta$` will generate the desired upright delta.  But the next update of MikTeX will likely clobber your edit (until they fix the problem).  The problem is not in libertine itself but in MikTeX.

Comment: That's a nice idea, but I'm specifically looking for the text delta, rather than the math delta. I've add a relevant image to the post. And presumably if I load `newtxtext`, it will overwrite `libertine`?

Comment: @Mohan:  no image posted.  Libertine has only one delta glyph and the libertine option of newtxmath is supposed to use it.  But I've tested this and it doesn't seem to work. I'm consulting the newtxmath maintainer.

Comment: The image is at the end of my post. (Can't put them in comments AFAIK.)

Comment: @Mohan: As I suggested but use \updelta:

Comment: I get > The rfxlr-alt source file could not be found. >!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file rfxlr-alt): Font rfxlr-alt at 600 not found

Comment: Enable newtx.map as a font-map; should have been done when the newtx package was installed.

Comment: BTW: [Bug filed in the MiKTeX Bug Tracker](https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2200/).