# Use greek in newcommand, LaTeX

Tags: macros, greek

[image]

I have problems with inserting the characters of the Greek alphabet in the source code. I like to use Greek also in mathematical formulas, but as you can see from the photo when you finish the compilation, the Greek changes to the normal Latin alphabet.
Besides this problem, I don't understand why in the `\newcommand` it doesn't accept Greek in order to rename old commands.

For example, why can't I use:

`\newcommand{∂}{\partial}`??? (in the case I can do it, how should I?)

code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage[italian, greek]{babel}

\newcommand{\fk}{\displaystyle\frac}
\newcommand{\MU}{\MakeUppercase} 
\newcommand{\mc}{\mathcal}
\newcommand{\mb}{\mathbb}
\newcommand{\Σ}{\Sigma}




\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{}
\[
d σκ  \Σ
\]

ξηκξαντονελλο μεψψαρειλλο


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, add the code as such. Are you using `pdflatex`, `xelatex` or `lualatex`? Are you getting errors?

Comment: You can do it [in any of these ways.])https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/601434/61644)

Comment: You can't `\newcommand` a \⟨Unicode character⟩ on pdflatex, see e.g. [macros - UTF-8 (but not in current font) character in newcommand - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101987/utf-8-but-not-in-current-font-character-in-newcommand)

Comment: What do you want to typeset exactly? Do you want to typeset the math sigma (`\sigma`) or the text sigma (`\text{σ}`)?

Comment: as an error I get --> Package Inputenc: Invalid UTF-8 byte "88.

Comment: I would like to use, for example, in the code, instead of \partial this one ∂ or \∂

Comment: See `newunicodechar` package, there's an example in the question linked above

Comment: thank you all, but i found the answer in adding this:\makeatletter
\@namedef{u8:\detokenize{ψ}}{\psi}
\makeatother