# Create a new math mode

Tags: math-mode

## Motivation

When I use math mode inside of `itemize` environments for multiline equations, I have to do something like the following

```
...
\begin{itemize}
  \item $\begin{aligned}[t]
    equation stuff
  \end{aligned}$
  ...
\end{itemize}
...
```

## Question

How can I wrap the two components `$\begin{aligned}[t]` and `\end{aligned}$` into a new symbol, e.g. `§`? I'd like to write the above example as

```
...
\begin{itemize}
  \item §equation stuff§
  ...
\end{itemize}
...
```

It is favorable for the solution to be robust.

---

(It is not required for the new symbol to be `§`.)

Comment: How about a macro `\mleq` defined as `\newcommand\mleq[1]{$\begin{aligned}[t] #1 \end{aligned}$`?

Comment: Unrelated: [Why is there a `\,` space at the beginning of the `aligned` environment?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98482)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Is it then not recommended to use `aligned`? What do you propose instead?

Comment: @HenriMenke No. I don’t know of a better alternative (except maybe an `array` solution). As you can see in the numerous linked references you will just to insert a `\!`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `` \catcode`§=\active `` method won't work if the document declares

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

because `§` is a two byte character in UTF-8. For this case you can use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{§}{\mymath}
\def\mymath#1§{$\begin{aligned}[t] #1\end{aligned}$}

\newenvironment{itemalign}
  {$\aligned[t]}
  {\endaligned$}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item §x&=2\\y&=6§
\item \begin{itemalign}x&=2\\y&=6\end{itemalign}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

that has the advantage of working also with LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX (where the call to `inputenc` should not be present).

However, I'd recommend using the new environment method.

[image]

Comment: You used `\aligned` to open the envorinment, but you used `\endalignedat` to close it (Note the trailing `at`). Anyway it works, but why? And why don't you use `\endaligned`?

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks for noting! I checked and discovered that `\endalignedat` executes `\endalign`. `;-)` But it's wrong anyway.

Comment: I used the `\newenvironment` solution. To make it more `align`-like I'd like to add a new line at the end of `itemalign`. I used `{\endaligned$\par}`, but I doubt, that this is the right procedure, because this will start a new paragaph after each `itemalign`. What do I have to insert instead of `\par`?

Comment: @HenriMenke I believe this should be the entire item, so you need nothing after it.

Answer (score 5):

How about making `§` active?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\catcode`§=\active
\def§#1§{$\begin{aligned}[t] #1\end{aligned}$}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item §x&=2\\y&=6§
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Then we can scan an argument up to the next occurence of `§` and wrap this in `aligned`.

---

As @egreg pointed out, this will be problematic using `pdflatex` and `inputenc` (see also: [Catcodes of unicode characters with \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86297/catcodes-of-unicode-characters-with-usepackageutf8inputenc)). A simple workaround in this case is changing `§` to e.g. `|`.

Comment: This would not work with `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`

Comment: @egreg fair point! It works with my `xelatex`, however, so I didn't notice. Changing the character from `§` to e.g. `|` fixes that though.

Answer (score 5):

If I were you, I would use two different macros to open and close the environment. I would do something like

```
\def\ba#1\ea{$\begin{aligned}[t]#1\end{aligned}$}
```

that can be use like that

```
\begin{itemize}
\item \ba equation stuff \ea
\end{itemize}
```